# Formula for calculating categories

Tags: excel

Looking for a optimal excel formula to achieve the following

0,1,2 < 2 days .... 3,4,5 < 5 Days..... 6,7 < 7 days.... 8,9,10 < 10 Days..... rest all > 10 Days

Example Table

Coulmn 1 has age and Column 2 should show a string

```
< 2 days or < 5 days or < 7 days or < 10 days or > 10 days
```

if the age = 0,1,2 column 2 should mention < 2 days
 .... 3,4,5 < 5 Days..... 6,7 < 7 days.... 8,9,10 < 10 Days..... rest all > 10 Days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of possible formulas that lend themselves to expandability.

[image: Less than days]

The formula in C1 is,

`=LOOKUP($A1, {0,3,6,8,11}, {"<2 days","<5 days","<7 days","<10 days","10+ days"})`

The formula in D1 is,

`=CHOOSE(1+($A1>2)+($A1>5)+($A1>7)+($A1>10), "<2 days","<5 days","<7 days","<10 days","10+ days")`

... or,

`=CHOOSE(MATCH(A1, {0,3,6,8,11}), "<2 days","<5 days","<7 days","<10 days","10+ days")`

Fill down as necessary.

Comment: Those formulas would likely benefit from removing the repetitious *" days"* and concatenating it once off the back end. e.g. `=LOOKUP($A1, {0,3,6,8,11}, {"<2","<5","<7","<10","10+"})&" days"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
=IF(col1<=2,"<2days",IF(col1<=5,"<5days",IF(col1<=7,"<7days",IF(col1<=10,"<10days",">10days"))))
```

where col1 is you column that contains the value you are checking. modify the condition accordingly

Comment: Nice one! I wasn't thinking that way.